# Using Cookie in Web activity in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I have provided Cookies in header as
Cookie : =; =; but then, it is giving following response when running on Self hosted IR and Size limit error when running on Azure IR

{ "Response": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n Sign in to your account\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n//<![CDATA[\n$Config=

Any solution for this?

Comment: what's the url look like? The cookie is stored in your browser, data factory can not get it.

Comment: I am using web activity, to retrive cookie details and another webactivity to authorize and retrieve the data.